# How to create internal links (href="#..." / PHP & Bootstrap

Tags: php, hyperlink, bootstrap-4, href

New to coding in general. Creating a simple small website as a class assignment. Using PHP with no frameworks and Bootstrap for the HTML-CSS. Cannot use JavaScript as per assignment requirements.

I cannot find how to properly create internal links in a page.

I use the URL to decide which page to show (all dealt from index.php). Links (via href) to diferent pages in the same website or external links work fine.

But when I try to use what normally would be href="#idName" for a link pointing to the same page, it doesn't work.

I assume it has something to do with how this information goes to the URL and is interpreted by the index.php. But besides that, I'm lost.

Maybe because I don't have the right vocabulary to search for it, but so far, no luck when looking for the answer online.

Part of the index.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
    if($_GET['action'] == 'profil-membre'){
        include('pages/header_menu.html'); 
        include('pages/profil-membre.php');
    }elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'page-activite'){
        include('pages/header_menu.html'); 
        include('pages/page-activite.php');
    }
}else{ 
    include('pages/header_menu.html'); 
    //and below the html for the main page.
?>
```

And part of the html in the pages where I would like an internal link:

```
 <!--a menu as tabs (showing just the part with the problematic href-->
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#membre-exist">Membre Existant</a>
</li>

<!-- the href should point to the div with id "membre-exist" -->
<div class="tab-content card card-body mb-4">
    <div id="membre-exist" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
        <form action=""> <!-- and the html code follows normally -->
```

Any ideas or links to where I could find the information to solve this would be appreciated!!

Comment: *Cannot use JavaScript as per assignment requirements.* - then your tabs wont work.. bootstrap requires its javascript for some components to work.

Comment: :) I cannot write it myself, but Boostrap is allowed, so it's implied the teacher is ok with whatever JS is used (created) by Bootstrap. Don't ask me why he has this arbitrary rules though!

Comment: Then your tabs should work if you included the lib and jQuery. Event selectors like `data-toggle="tab"` use `href="#membre-exist"` to set an active class on `class="container tab-pane fade"`... He's probably trying to keep you focused on the PHP, as if you use js, like Vue or react, it makes for a whole lot richer UI and easier, but tends to lead you away from PHP.

Comment: @TimONets not sure how you can to the conclusion, that using simple php templates magically makes it MVC ... post edited.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone,  I had created the page without PHP first and it was working just fine... I'm thinking the problem is more the way I use PHP and how it interprets the "#member-exist" via the URL.

Comment: @tereško, not sure I understand your comment. I'm using no PHP templates, I write the code myself. Do you think this has any impact on how the links are behaving? Would you have an idea on how to solve it?

Comment: @tereško, but the part where the index.php is dealing with all the requests is important in my question. I know how to create an internal link on a static page. What I don't know is how to create it in the context of all pages being dealt from the index.php. This index.php file is going to receive all the requests. This means that every link would have to point to /?x=y, but how to do that when what is needed is an internal link? This "#idName" ends going through the URL, but then it looks like index.php doesn't know what to do with it. How to write these hrefs in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `:target` CSS pseudo element and use that to show the contents using `display`. I am doing something really simple for you.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 1; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; text-align: center; border-radius: 5px;}
a {display: inline-block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccf; background-color: #eef; text-decoration: none;}
a:active, a:focus {background: #f90; border-color: #f60;}
section {margin: 10px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccf; background-color: #f5f5f5; display: none;}
section:target {display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="#one">one</a>
<a href="#two">two</a>
<a href="#three">three</a>
<a href="#four">four</a>

<section id="one">
  This is section one.
</section>
<section id="two">
  This is section two.
</section>
<section id="three">
  This is section three.
</section>
<section id="four">
  This is section four.
</section>
```

The above code acts like a tab view and it doesn't have any JavaScript or Server Side code. It purely relies on the `#hashvalue` that's passed to the URL. The above code perfectly matches with your requirement:

- Doesn't use any server side language.
- Doesn't require JavaScript for this.

It's a pure CSS way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have thought of this option. I'll keep in mind for future projects. For this one, finally my problem was that I had done a bad copy/paste elsewhere ... :\